# Copy data from one sheet to another in reverse order using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets in my excel PullData and AllStocks. I would like to copy data from PullData column A and paste the values reverse order into other sheet AllStocks.

Currently, I am using OFFSET function to perform it. But I see a performance issue while running large data set using this method. Is there any better way I can perform this task ?

My CUrrent Code :

```
Sub GetData()
Dim Main As Worksheet
Dim PullData As Worksheet
Dim AllStocks As Worksheet
Dim i,m As Integer


Set RawImport = Workbooks("vwap.xlsm").Sheets("RawImport")
Set PullData = Workbooks("vwap.xlsm").Sheets("PullData")

m = PullData.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 3 To m

AllStocks.Range("A2:A" & i).Formula = "=OFFSET(PullData!$A$" & m & ",-(ROW(PullData!A1)-1),0)"

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you repeatedly write the same formula into the "A2:A" & i range?

Comment: @Jeeped: I am trying to get the formula for the entire range which equals to my source A column. Is there any better way ? I am not an very much new to this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no loop code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetData()        
    Dim pullDataVals As Variant

    With Workbooks("vwap.xlsm")
        With .Sheets("PullData")
            pullDataVals = Split(StrReverse(Join(Application.Transpose(.Range("A3", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value), ",")), ",")
        End With

        .Sheets("RawImport").Range("A2").Resize(UBound(pullDataVals) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(pullDataVals)
    End With     
End Sub
```

just check your sheets names: in your question you're speaking about *"PullData and AllStocks"* but in your code some `RawImport` sheet is featuring...

or, in a super compressed style:

```
Sub GetData()
    With Workbooks("vwap.xlsm").Sheets("PullData")
        With .Range("A3", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
            .Parent.Parent.Sheets("RawImport").Range("A2").Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(Split(StrReverse(Join(Application.Transpose(.Value), ",")), ","))
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

---

should your data in `PullData` be a more than one character string or more than one digit number, to prevent what Gary's Student remarked, you could use `ArrayList` object and its `Reverse` method:

```
Sub GetData()
    Dim arr As Object
    Dim cell As Range

    Set arr = CreateObject("System.Collections.Arraylist")
    With Workbooks("vwap.xlsm")
        With .Sheets("PullData")
            For Each cell In .Range("A3", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
                arr.Add cell.Value
            Next
        End With
        arr.Reverse
        .Sheets("RawImport").Range("A2").Resize(arr.Count) = Application.Transpose(arr.toarray)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This code does reverse the order of the cells, but it also reverses the order of the characters **within** each cell.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent, you're right. So I added a code for a more-than-one-character string or a more-than-one-digit number case (a very likely one, indeed)

Comment: @DisplayName:If I need only last 5 rows to be copied, how can I change it

Comment: You could use: For Each cell In .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(-4).Resize(5)

Answer (score 0):

This solution applies the `INDEX` formula to a temporary `Name`.

```
Sub Range_ReverseOrder()
Const kFml As String = "=INDEX(_Src,#RowsSrc+#RowTrg-ROW(),1)"
Dim nmSrc As Name, rgTrg As Range
Dim lRows As Long, sFml As String

    Rem Set Objects
    With Workbooks("vwap.xlsm")
        lRows = .Worksheets("PullData").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set nmSrc = .Names.Add(Name:="_Src", _
             RefersTo:=.Worksheets("PullData").Cells(2, 1).Resize(-1 + lRows, 1))
        .Names("_Src").Comment = "Range_ReverseOrder"
        Set rgTrg = .Worksheets("RawImport").Cells(2, 1).Resize(-1 + lRows, 1)
    End With

    Rem Set Formula
    sFml = kFml
    sFml = Replace(sFml, "#RowsSrc", nmSrc.RefersToRange.Rows.Count)
    sFml = Replace(sFml, "#RowTrg", rgTrg.Row)

    Rem Apply Formula
    With rgTrg
        .Offset(-1).Resize(1).Value = "Reverse.Order"
        .Formula = sFml
        .Value2 = .Value2
    End With

    Rem Delete Temporary Name
    nmSrc.Delete

    End Sub
```